# Let $f(x)=7x^{32}+5x^{22}+3x^{12}+x^2$. Find the remainder when $x^2+1$ divides $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, polynomials

Let $f(x)=7x^{32}+5x^{22}+3x^{12}+x^2$. Find the remainder when $x^2+1$ divides $f(x)$ and $xf(x)$.

I tried this problem two ways, substituting $x=1,-1$ in $f(x)$ to find the remainder, and by long division, but, that's not getting me to the answer. I think there is a shorter and elegant technique for solving this question. Please help. Thank you.r

Comment: Hint,$x^2+1|f(x) \iff x^2+1|xf(x)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=x^2$. We want the remainder when $Q(t)=7t^{16}+5t^{11}+3t^6+t$ is divided by $t+1$. By the Remainder Theorem, this is $Q(-1)$.

For the second question, multiply the answer to the first by $x$.

Comment: That was simply brilliant. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. It was really very natural, and not at all brilliant.

Comment: This might be a little off-topic, but would you recommend some books where I can find some brilliant natural techniques?

Comment: Unfortunately not for this class of problem.  The Remainder Theorem is a standard tool. Your substitution process will not work as stated, though using $\pm i$ (the square roots of $-1$, the roots of $x^2+1=0$, will work even for polynomials $g(x)$ which involve both even and odd powers of $x$.

Comment: Ok, that is fine. But, if you have any books in mind, according to my level, then please do recommend. And, thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: +1 for including the natural suggestion to look at $f(\pm i)$.